# C project with multiple files (header files)

Tags: c, project, header-files

I'm fairly new to the C language, but have acquired some experience. Now I'm on my way creating larger projects with (more or less) complex data structures (e.g. Map (I will use Maps as an example thoughout)). Since I want my data structure code to be reusable for future projects, I like them being rather generic and in separate files.
Since C doesn't use/have Generics (like Java) oder Templates (like C++) or any similar concept I thought about using a globally defined data type like

```
typedef union {
    int integer;
    char * str;
    // etc.
} data_t;
```

and put that in a `main.h` which will be included into all other (header) files (possible using guards). This works fairly well for me, but …

**is there a way to integrate data structures into my `data_t` (which include `main.h` to use `data_t`) ?**
The simple-but-obviously-not-working (due to circular includes) solution is to `#include "map.h"` in `main.h` while also including `main.h` in `map.h`; as mentioned, this doesn't work for obvious reasons.
Basically I want a Map that can hold other Maps, all while using only one `data_t` and one Map-implementation. Keeping track of which "layer" I am on will be done in the surrounding program (or maybe I can add some info in the `data_t` about its type, this is not the focus here).
I know that this will be possible when just using a `void *`; but I don't want unnecessary references for primitive datatypes like `int` if I don't have to.

Is there any clean way to do such behavior ?

Thank you !
(if any actual code is needed, tell me)

### actual code

`main.h` which I want to contain general declarations like my `data_t`:

```
#ifndef _MAIN_H_
#define _MAIN_H_

#include "map.h"

typedef union {
    int integer;
    char * str;
    map_t map;
} data_t;

#endif
```

`map.h`:

```
#ifndef _MAP_H_
#define _MAP_H_

#include "main.h"

typedef char * key_t;

typedef struct {
    int (*hash_f)(key_t);
    int size;
    data_t * data;
} map_t;

int map_init(map_t * map, int (*hash_f)(key_t key));
int map_put(map_t map, key_t key, data_t data);
int map_get(map_t map, key_t key);

#endif
```

compiling with `make`:

```
% make
gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -g -c main.c -o build/main.o
In file included from main.c:1:
./main.h:8:5: error: unknown type name 'map_t'
    map_t map;
    ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [build/main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Please give an example of what is in `map.h`. And why does it need `main.h`? That is, give a concrete and complete code example of what you are trying to do. Describing things in words is rarely precise or clear enough.

Comment: Your question may be too broad for a specific stackoverflow answer. But anyway, C does not have templates. For templates, use C++.

Comment: The two choices you have for generic code in C are macros and void * (3rd option would be external code generation).

Comment: Not clear on what is the exact issue that you are facing here, if you are looking for an options to avoid a data type to be used in multiple header files and wrapper functions. use a "void*" instead to pass address across functions, and converet the data type to desired format in functions definitions where its required. and only include ".h" files in ".c" files.

Comment: In C++ you will have the same circular dependency, as I understand your issue. Please show us a concrete example ([edit] you question and add it), even if it will not compile.

Comment: In C you should use void pointer for example you can create one linked list and use it for any project using `malloc()' and void pointer

Comment: Take inspiration from the source code of existing open source software like [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [GTK](http://gtk.org/)

Comment: If you make `map_t` in `data_t` a pointer, then you can forward declare `map_t` and do not need to include `map.h`. In principle, the specific header file, `map.h` should not be included in the more general file, `data_t`. Many users of `data_t` would have no interest in knowing the details of `map_t`. Another issue is that your general idea is in danger of being an example of the so-called Softcoding anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Get your declarations and typedefinitions working within one source code file.
When that compiles, think what to put in a header. That way you make sure that at first you see what the compiler sees for one (each) code file your header gets included into.

If you cannot get it to work within one non-including code file, then you have a problem that cannot be solved with headers and guards.
If however you can do it, then just look at the single file and think "Now what do I want to also use in the next code file?" and put that into a header. (Make of course sure to only move declarations, typedefs, macro-defs into a header. Code, variable definitions do not go into headers.)

Circular dependencies cannot be solved by guards, only redefinitions due to (indirect) multiple inclusion.